# Load calendar with next upcoming event

Tags: events, calendar, business-catalyst

Is there a way to load the calendar in Business Catalyst with the next upcoming event if there are no events in the current month, instead of loading the current month as default?

Comment: May be possible with some javascript work. Each day that has an event is marked with a class of `event`. The idea that I think would work is check each day to see if it has the class of event. If no days in the month have that class, then switch the the next month using (JS to do this), keep repeating until it finds an event. That is a rough concept I think would work.

Comment: Thanks Lynda, I suspected as much :P I am a novice to js, but I guess looping through a collection with some sort of do while loop on a calendar object, and then exit the loop when the class event is found and show that month?